# Showing Black Screen on Android in react-native-jitsi-meet

Tags: android, react-native, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

The Jitsi Meet neither JitsiMeetView nor Jitsi Extended Activity is just showing black screen on android

"react-native": "0.66.4"
"react-native-jitsi-meet":"2.2.0"

anyone can help here?

Answer (score 0):

put your function in      `useEffect(()=>{ }, [])`     and call
`JitsiMeet.call()`     functions after 1000 mili secs;;

Like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(makeJitsiCall, 2000);
    return () => {
      JitsiMeet.endCall();
    };
  }, [route.params])
```